# Find the matching total Qty in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need your help here, the below is sample data that I need to find the matching request qty. Let's say request qty is 90. So in the query can auto search all the possibility of matching the total sum qty.

For example, the results can be possible combination with IDs:-

1. 2 + 10 = 90
2. 3 + 8 = 90
3. 5 + 6 = 90
4. 4 + 7 = 90
5. 6 + 7 + 8 = 90
   .
   .
   .

I understand the combination formula can doing this in sql server, 
n!/(n-r)!(r!). But it can be slowdown the query execution time if we have thousand of rows that need to be find the qty matching.

But I only want to find the FIRST match qty is enough instead of generate the entire list of combination possibility.

In this case, do you have any ideas or sample query that can making query run faster on above scenario besides combination?

```
+----+----------+-----+
| ID | Material | Qty |
+----+----------+-----+
|  1 | A        |  90 |
|  2 | A        |  80 |
|  3 | A        |  70 |
|  4 | A        |  60 |
|  5 | A        |  50 |
|  6 | A        |  40 |
|  7 | A        |  30 |
|  8 | A        |  20 |
|  9 | A        |  20 |
| 10 | A        |  10 |
+----+----------+-----+
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! Then you don't need any of those messy `<br />` tags, either!

Comment: How do you define which is the first match? Or do you mean that any exact match is ok?

Comment: Assuming you're only worried about the query speed and not too bothered by WHICH two are chosen then won't `TOP 1` in your SELECT statement work? SQL Server should then end the query as soon as it finds the first one

Comment: Please pay attention to how people have to edit your questions and/or please make use of the *preview* which appears below the editing box, to see what the final formatting looks like.

Comment: I would say that if you want to post data, first use [**this tool**](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) to format the data into a table-like format, for easier readability and a more pleasant look. This is **not** my tool and I'm not trying to advertise, I just use it everytime I try to format my data and I think it's way much better than manually beautifying.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu - for SQL questions, I would *far* rather have a syntactically correct (set of) `INSERT` statement(s) than a "pleasant" table that I have to *remove* formatting from before I can start working with the data.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Agreed, that would be a far better version. I would even go one step further and ask for a [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with the data.

Comment: Yes JamesZ, any exact match is ok. As long as it can find the first match qty = 90, then it will exit the subsequent finding...

Comment: Is there anybody can show the sample query would be much better.